# Expected value of square[X/sigmaX] = 1/n^2(1+1/pi)?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, limit-theorems

Please see the below link for the complete description. I already have an answer shown in the link, based on many Excel simulations ($n=4$ to $100$, $x_i$ generated by RAND() function of Excel). I want to know if the answer $\frac{1}{n^2}\left(1+\frac{1}{\pi}\right)$ has a theoretical basis. If no, how to derive as a function of $n$? Thanks.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j7yvuysxiBI7uMrOiaHzS8kxzUfhy3VL/view?usp=sharing

---

(Added by David Roberts) The file says:
$$
E\left[\left(\frac{x_1}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}\right)^2\right] = 
\frac{1}{n^2}\left(1+\frac{1}{\pi} \right)
$$
where $x_i \sim U(0,1)$.

Comment: I removed an irrelevant tag. As this question stands, it's not really a good fit for this site. Partly because it isn't self-contained (this is a StackExchange thing, not MO per se) and the Google Drive link will eventually rot. But secondly, if the question were cleaned up and made self-contained, it might be better at stats.stackechange.com

Comment: Please note that this is a very challenging problem, and MO may be a better place for this. I am not sure how to write equations thats why the google drive, but that link will remain forever.

Comment: Just because it is challenging, doesn't mean that a statistics-specific forum is not a better place to ask this. I have edited the question to be self-contained and include your hypothesised formula.

Comment: Thanks David, how do I write equations like you did? Is there a tool?

Comment: how do you explain $n=1$? Is this meant to be asymptotic?

Comment: @Murali if you click edit on the question (or any question here) you can see the source from which MathJax renders the maths.It uses a subset of the LaTeX syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your conjecture is obviously false for $n=1$, and I think it is false for any $n$. Using the [Irwin-Hall formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution), one can write an explicit but very complicated expression for the expectation in question, and that expression will not involve $\pi$.

Also, the conjecture is false for all large enough $n$. More specifically, letting 
$$
m_n:=Er_n^2,\quad r_n:=\frac{nx_1}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}=\frac{x_1}{\bar x_n},\quad \bar x_n:=\frac1n\,\sum_{i=1}^n x_i, 
$$
we have 
$$
\lim\inf_n n^2 E\Big(\frac{x_1}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}\Big)^2=\lim\inf_n m_n\ge\frac43>1+\frac1\pi. \tag{1}
$$
Indeed, by the [strong law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law), $\bar x_n\to Ex_1=\frac12$ almost surely (a.s.) and hence $r_n\to2x_1$ a.s. Also, $Ex_1^2=\frac13$. So, by the [Fatou lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma),
$$\lim\inf_n m_n=\lim\inf_n Er_n^2\ge E(2x_1)^2=4Ex_1^2=4/3,
$$
so that the first inequality in (1) follows.

---

Working a bit harder, we can show that actually $m_n\to\frac43$, that is, 
$$
E\Big(\frac{x_1}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}\Big)^2\sim\frac4{3n^2}. \tag{2}
$$ 
Indeed, by [Hoeffding's inequality for sums of independent bounded random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality#General_case_of_bounded_random_variables), we have $P(\bar x_n<1/4)\le e^{-n/8}$. Also, obviously $0\le r_n\le n$. So,
$$Er_n^21_{\bar x_n<1/4}\le n^2P(\bar x_n<1/4)\le n^2e^{-n/8}\to0. 
$$
On the other hand, $r_n^21_{\bar x_n\ge1/4}\le1/(1/4)^2<\infty$ and $r_n^21_{\bar x_n\ge1/4}\to4x_1^2$ a.s., again by the strong law of large numbers. So, by dominated convergence, 
$$Er_n^21_{\bar x_n\ge1/4}\to4Ex_1^2=\frac43. 
$$
Thus,
$$m_n=Er_n^2=Er_n^21_{\bar x_n<1/4}+Er_n^21_{\bar x_n\ge1/4}\to0+\frac43=\frac43,
$$
as claimed. That is, we have (2).

Comment: I tried for n=4, 10, 18, 100. My conjecture is true. As an example, please see the calculation for n=4 in the Excel file in the below link.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GslVYM69qPdLQH8S7ZY_Wtcqt2iJbO8D/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Note that A to D columns were generated by RAND() function. E is the function I asked for. G is the expected value and I is my formula. It may not match to the 3rd decimal, but then, there are 4000+ random data, not theoretically infinite.

Comment: For $n=4$, an exact integration gives $\frac{1}{2} - 22 \ln(2) + \frac{27}{2} \ln(3)$.  This is not the same as $\frac{1}{16} \left(1 + \frac{1}{\pi}\right)$.

Comment: Thanks, the two do match upto the 3rd decimal I think. But your replies and the derivation by Losif have been very informative. Thanks. Can you kindly suggest a book where I can read about Irwin-Hall theorem and Hoeffding's inequality theorems?

Comment: @Murali: Your conjecture has been disproved for $n=1$, $n=4$ (in the comment by Robert Israel), and for all large enough $n$ (in my answer). Therefore, you cannot maintain that the conjecture is true for all $n$, even if you get somewhat close matches with the conjectured value in your simulations for some $n$.

Comment: @Murali : You don't need to read books to learn the Irwin--Hall formula and Hoeffding's inequality. The latter you can find at the link provided in my answer (the original paper by Hoeffding is at https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1963.10500830), and the Irwin--Hall formula can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution.

Comment: Excel is definitely not the appropriate tool for such simulations. You can use almost any programming language. For n = 4 I got the following values after 7 seconds with the following simple program in python: import numpy as np
from math import log

x = np.random.rand(100000000)
y = np.random.rand(100000000)
u = np.random.rand(100000000)
v = np.random.rand(100000000)
s = x+y+u+v
values = (x/s)**2
print(values.mean())
print(0.5-22*log(2)+27/2*log(3))
0.08202720113495676
0.08202792470068587
In particular this confirms the Robert Israel value.

Comment: May be true, however, Excel's RAND() function surely generates random numbers from a uniform distribution from (0 to 1). When I generate 4000 such numbers and find its variance, it is ~ 0.083, (which is 1/12, expected of a uniform distribution)

Comment: @Murali: Excel certainly does not generate random numbers. What it does is produce a deterministic sequence of pseudorandom numbers, which hopefully approximates some properties of truly random numbers -- which latter cannot actually be obtained by any physical processes, because (say) a sequence of iid random variables is pure abstraction. The proper way to deal with such abstractions is by means of mathematical proof. In this, simulations may be useful only as suggestions for a proof.

Comment: Previous comment continued: Also, even if you had a realization of a sequence of truly random numbers, still, because of random fluctuations, you would not be able to reach the kind of conclusion you desire here by any calculations involving any finite subsequence of such random numbers.

Comment: @Murali:When I studied physics long ago then we were told, that to estimate the "true" mean of a given series we should apply the following method (of course this method is not good!): compute the mean $m$ and the standard derivative $s$ of the series given. Then the true mean is $m \pm s$, i.e. is between $m-s$ and $m+s$. I repeated this method with 3 series of length $3000$ and got intervals $[0.08287,0.08597]$, $[0.08216,0.08514]$, $[0.08165,0.08470]$. My question: Do you have any idea what the true mean is? It is irrelevant here if the value of the series are truely random.

Comment: @Ioseph: Can you please elaborate how you get equation (1), especially \lim\inf_n m_n\ge\frac43

Comment: @Murali : I have added details on this.